# Can a PC be used as a power source for an Xbox One controller?

Tags: controllers, xbox-one

I can use a power outlet to power my Xbox One controller using a USB charger. 
My laptop also gives my Xbox One controller power but instead registers as a plug and play device and doesn't connect to the Xbox One but instead works on the PC as a gamepad.

Is there anyway I can make it so the PC just supplies power the Xboe One controller instead of making it a gamepad?

Comment: One way that it might work is to remove the controller from Windows' devices and make sure it ain't recognized again by Windows. That part will be hard to do as it is connected to computer. Another thing you might try is to have the controller detected/connected to the Xbox before connecting it to the computer. Windows might not be able to override the existing connection.

Comment: I would really like to know if the "connect to Xbox One first" solution works. Something for me to test when I get a new controller..

Comment: @Timelord64 I have the controller but not the xbox one to test it. I use it for pc games where a gamepad is better.

Comment: Between me and you, @Jonathan Drapery, we have one, fully functioning Xbox one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the eventuality you have a spare usb cable that you don't use for anything else, you can put some thin tape on the data pins (the two middle ones) and it will turn it into a power only cable. The PC simply won't see your gamepad while still powering it.

[image: tape over usb data pins]

The image is from "[Make a USB cable 'power only'](http://www.instructables.com/id/USB-Condom/)"

Comment: As a side note, USB is a connection standard. They generally share the same voltage, so you do not need to worry about a USB power adapter short circuiting your controller. Furthermore, you should find that if you connect the Xbox One controller to your phone with an on the go cable, your phone will no problem identifying it. I have only confirmed support with an Xbox 360 controller on an Android device, but using @spenibus answer, you should be able to use your phone as a portable battery pack. You can also get power banks that should give you 20-25 hours for 10 bucks. Convenience.